# How to save custom added field in an extended user creation form in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am pretty new to Django and i made a custom signup form by extending the UserCreationForms in Django.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm): #This class will be used in views of account to make sigupform
user_type = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Select(choices=usertypes))
email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'user_type','email','password1','password2']
def save(self,commit=True):
    user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.user_type = self.cleaned_data['user_type']
    print('Flag3')
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

It is working fine with the view :

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    print('Flag0')
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        if user.user_type == 'Seller' or user.user_type=='seller':
            print('Flag1')
            auth_login(request, user)
            print('Flag2')
            print(user.user_type)
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Seller')
            print(group.name)
            print('Flag3')
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('get_seller')
        if user.user_type == 'Customer' or user.user_type=='customer':
            print('Flag1')
            auth_login(request, user)
            print('Flag2')
            print(user.user_type)
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
            print(group.name)
            print('Flag3')
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('home')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

I added flags because is was checking the progress of the form.

**The problem that i am facing is that i want to save the custom field that made `user_type`** .

I don't know how to save the custom field or if it is being saved how to get the value.

Update:I printed the `user.user_type` .
[image: Server Console]
By :
`def save(self,commit=True):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.user_type = self.cleaned_data['user_type']
        print(user.user_type)`

Comment: What value do you have inside `self.cleaned_data['user_type']`?

Comment: @HigorRossato ``usertypes= [
    ('customer', 'Customer'),
    ('seller', 'Seller'),
    ]``
If that if what you are asking.Otherwise i don't have a clue.

Comment: In your `SignUpForm` you're overriding the `save` method. Inside that method, you're calling `self.cleaned_data['user_type']`. Can you print that?

Comment: @HigorRossato Yes, it is printable. It is printing customer when customer is selected seller for seller type.I have added the screenshot at the question's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's User Model does not have `user_type` field. If you want `user_type` field to be part of Django's User Model. Then use `AbstractUser` model and create a custom user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_lenght=20, choices=usertypes)
```

Now use this custom model, while create a your form.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out.

Comment: I just came back to this... Creating an AbstractUser leads to many open ends with save not working ,Django Managers not able to handle the requests.. etc (Not recommended for a beginner to user) . An alternative could be using a foreign key in another of user and storing the extra data there. Redirect the user to another form once he or she finished creating account.